# Unknown column 'e2.evaluationID' in 'on clause' ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE EVALUATION e join
           (select e.*,
                   (select sum(readamount)
                    FROM EVALUATION e2
                    where e2.userId = e.userId and e2.readday <= e.readamount
                   ) as running_readamount
            FROM EVALUATION e
           ) ee
           on e.evaluationID = e2.evaluationID
        set e.readamount = e2.running_readamount;
```

As a result of running the following MYSQL statements:

The error message **'Unknown column 'e2.evaluationID' in 'on clause''** is printed.
What's wrong?

```
evaluationID | userID | readday | readamount
---------------------------------------------
1            | aaa    | Day 1   | 20
---------------------------------------------
2            | bbb    | Day 1   | 10
---------------------------------------------
3            | ccc    | Day 1   | 30
---------------------------------------------
4            | aaa    | Day 2   | 50
---------------------------------------------
5            | bbb    | Day 2   | 30
---------------------------------------------
6            | ccc    | Day 2   | 40
---------------------------------------------
```

We would like to modify the data in this form as follows:

I want to make the "readmount" value accumulate gradually according to the "readday" value.

For your information, my MYSQL version is 5.6.

```
evaluationID | userID | readday | readamount
---------------------------------------------
1            | aaa    | Day 1   | 20
---------------------------------------------
2            | bbb    | Day 1   | 10
---------------------------------------------
3            | ccc    | Day 1   | 30
---------------------------------------------
4            | aaa    | Day 2   | **70**
---------------------------------------------
5            | bbb    | Day 2   | **40**
---------------------------------------------
6            | ccc    | Day 2   | **70**
---------------------------------------------
```

```
※ TABLE name = EVALUATION
   `evaluationID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `userID` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `readday` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `readamount` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: `e2.evaluationID` is inside a subquery and is not visible in the main (outer) query. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That should be `ee`:

```
UPDATE EVALUATION e join
           (select e.*,
                   (select sum(readamount)
                    FROM EVALUATION e2
                    where e2.userId = e.userId and e2.readday <= e.readday
                   ) as running_readamount
            FROM EVALUATION e
           ) ee
           on e.evaluationID = ee.evaluationID
        set e.readamount = ee.running_readamount;
```

Comment: P.Salmon, how should I correct the sentence "e2.readday <= e.readamount"?

Comment: @P.Salmon . . . Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

```
update EVALUATION  set readamount = qry.ramt
from
(select e.evaluationID , sum(e.readamount) as ramt from EVALUATION e 
where readday <= readamount
group by e.evaluationID) qry
where
EVALUATION.evaluationID = qry.evaluationID;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. @Payin, if there is an error message, please share it

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from (select e.evaluationID, sum(e.readamount) as ramt from EVALUATION wher' at line 2

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Just need add an alias e in the subquery. Added now please check

Comment: @Jim Macaulay, I'm a beginner, so I don't know where the subquery is and where to put the e...

Comment: @Jim Macaulay, I see the same error as before... I think it would be better for me to study SQL a little more. Thank you for your reply :)